# Input Loop trouble

Tags: c, arrays, printing

What I've done is ask a user to input how many times the program will loop, it then records values into 3 different arrays. Everything is working great, but what I need it to do is print the elements of one array if the corresponding element in another array meets the requirements. Everything else runs great, I'll post the two arrays that I'm trying to use for this.

```
char *names[50][32];
char *states[50][2];
  i = 0;
while ( i < b) {
    if (state[i] = "tx");{
      printf("a string %s\n",  names[i]);}
      i = i + 1;
   }
```

for this : `if (state[i] = "tx");{` I've tried with and without quotes and using 116120...

Basically, it asks for peoples names and where they live. I can get it to print the array element values for each name(it runs in a loop) but I want it to only print the names for the people who live in tx.

Comment: Hint: what does the `;` in `if (state[i] = "tx");{` do?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `state` is not declared.

Comment: Also the `=` operator is assignment not comparison

Comment: yeah i just figured out the = for the ==, it still prints all arrays of char names, and not just the ones where the state is tx

Comment: also if i take ; out of the if (state[i] = "tx");{  then it doesnt run any of the if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all ending an `if` or `for` construction with a semicolon is a common mistake when starting in C. Basically it creates an empty `if` statement followed by a code block. Look at it this way:

```
if (condition)
   ; // Does nothing. The if is empty

// Totally unrelated block of code.
{
}
```

Code blocks are usually useful to create scopes, so although it might seem useless for the compiler to interpret blocks in this way, it actually is not. This also happens in other situations, such as `while`, `for`, and so on:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i)
     ; // Empty for. Runs `n` loops, but doing nothing

// Unrelated block of code. Runs only once
{
}
```

The comparison operator is also wrong, you should use `==` for comparisons, instead of `=`, which is used for assignments.

Finally, you cannot compare strings in this way. Strings are basically arrays, which in turn are represented using pointers. If you compare two pointers (`ptr1 == ptr2`) it'll only check whether the two strings point at the same address in memory. As strings are composed by several characters, they have to be iterated to be properly compared. Fortunately the standard library already provides a method for this.

Fix a typo or two and this is what you get:

```
char *names[50][32];
char *states[50][2];
  i = 0; // Assuming this is declared somewhere else
while ( i < b) {
    if (strcmp(states[i], "tx") == 0) {
      printf("a string %s\n",  names[i]);
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

You should probably also check the docs for [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Edit: as this is already the accepted answer, I should also include a fix as noted by @dbush. The array for stats is clearly missing space for the extra string terminator, as strings are `NULL` terminated in C. The array for names might or might not suffer from the same issue, it's not clear. Anyway, it's notable that both should include an extra byte for storing the terminator:

```
char names[50][33];
char states[50][3];
```

Props to @dbush.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will check out strcmp, i've never heard of it before

Comment: In that case, I recommend that you take a look at the docs for [string.h/cstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/). Get to know the string functions in C, they are useful for several scenarios.

Comment: See my edit. @dbush noticed something I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your arrays don't look correct:

```
char *names[50][32];
char *states[50][2];
```

These declare a pair of two-dimensional array of char pointers, which is probably not what you want.

```
char names[50][32];
char states[50][3];
```

These are two-dimensional arrays of characters, or alternately arrays of strings.  Note that the `states` array has space for an extra character for the terminating NULL.

In this `if` statement this:

```
if (state[i] = "tx");{
```

Since the `;` occurs immediately after the condition, that ends the `if` block.  The following statements within curly braces therefore will always run.  Also, `=` is for assignment, not comparison, but using `==` is not appropriate either, since that operator won't compare the strings, but their addresses.  You need to use `strcmp` for string comparisons.

So the fixed code should look like this:

```
char names[50][32];
char states[50][3];

...

i = 0;
while ( i < b) {
    if (strcmp(state[i],"tx") == 0) {
        printf("a string %s\n",  names[i]);
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` should compare to zero!

Comment: @AndréFratelli  Thanks.  Fixed

Comment: Also notice that you forgot about the extra byte for the null terminator on the last sample. As my answer was already accepted I included that and gave you credit. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AndréFratelli No problem.  Fixes that in my answer as well.